# JSON API Plugin is Used in Wordpress to Fetch data in mobile application but issue is that it takes so much time

Tags: json, wordpress, api

I have one website developed in wordpress and mobile application is also there here m using JSON API to fetch data from Wordpress.

But the issue that i m facing is that it's taking too much time to respond the data.

Can anyone help me how can i improve performance??

Currently it's taking almost 30 to 60 second to load data.

Here is the Link of my JSON API.
http://krantibhaskar.com/?json=get_posts&custom_fields=_mp_featured_video&count=9&date_query%5B0%5D%5Bbefore%5D=201801301218

Please give me suggestion how can i improve performance..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try caching your data on your api endpoint, if your json data is fetch from a database then maybe you can cache that on a file.

Another approach would be to use paging. Only retrieve data that you currently need.

You can even combine the two.
If still not good enough, try enabling compression on your api endpoint. This will help if your client has slow connection.